# Dart JS interop - Passing JS context as argument

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, interop

How to pass the context from Dart to JavaScript?

I'm trying this:

## JS Function

```js
function foo(this, (arg) {
    console.log(arg);
});
```

## Dart

```dart
@JS("LibJS")
library libjs;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS("foo")
external dynamic foo(dynamic context, dynamic function);

void main() {
  var obj = foo(context, (arg) {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
@JS() // if your JS call isn't LibJS.foo() then remove the string
library libjs;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS() // no need to add the "foo" if the name of the function is foo
external dynamic foo(dynamic context, Function() function);

void main() {
  var obj = foo(context, allowInterop((arg) {
     return 'hello';
  }));
}
```

Comment: if it solve, please mark as answer to help others @Gustavo